# My gVim (8.1, Win10) does NOT invoke $VIM\_vimrc during initialization

Tags: vimrc, gvim, microsoft-windows

My `$VIM\_vimrc` is as follows:

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
```

My `$HOME\_vimrc` does **not** have this option. I was led to believe that Vim first invokes the system `_vimrc` in `$VIM`, then moves on to the user `_vimrc` in their respective `$HOME`s, but it's obvious here that that's no longer the case here. This is important because I need to move all of my personal configs somewhere else, and `$VIM` is not a good option. Any help would be appreciated.

### Edit 1

After the use of `:scriptnames` as per recommendations of the comment below, I found that indeed, a) `$VIM\_vimrc` was **not used**, and b) the first file used was `$HOME\_vimrc`. I need Vim to use, first and foremost, `$VIM\_vimrc`, so that Vim recognizes `$HOME` to be elsewhere of the `C:\Users\foo` that I currently use.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. To see the files that are sourced by Vim, enter the command `:scriptnames`.

Comment: I've just added the observations after `:scriptnames` in the original question.

Comment: I found out that Vim only uses `$HOME/_vimrc` if it exists and overlooks `$VIM/_vimrc`. Guess I'll need to move my `$HOME/_vimrc` somewhere else and make **that** directory `$HOME`.

Comment: I still don't get what you want to do and why you want to do it.

Comment: I wanted to change my `$HOME` directory. It was for a personal project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `:help vimrc` for a detailed understanding of how `_vimrc`s work:

When Vim loads, it invokes `_vimrc`s in the following steps:

1. `$VIM/vimrc`
2. The first existing file of

   1. `$HOME/_vimrc`
   2. `$HOME/vimfiles/_vimrc`
   3. `$VIM/_vimrc`

`$VIM/vimrc` is the system-wide config file. `$VIM/_vimrc` is a user-defined config file used if the two `$HOME` files above are not defined.

Comment: The name of the system wide vimrc is `$VIM/vimrc`. Note the missing underscore

Comment: Right, my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: No, it's still not correct, `$VIM/vimrc` is always read. Then the first one of `$HOME/_vimrc`, `$HOME/vimfiles/vimrc`, or `$VIM/_vimrc` (this time with a leading underscore) is read. Vim also accepts a leading dot instead of an underscore. Note that you can have both `$VIM/vimrc` and `$VIM/_vimrc`, the first one as a system wide initialization file and the second one as a user initialization file which is ignored if `$HOME/_vimrc` exists. When you look at `:help vimrc`, steps a. to d. define the order of initialization. The part about the vimrc files before step a. is just informative.

Comment: Oh, I probably didn't have `$VIM/vimrc` in the first place, that's why it wasn't on `:scriptnames`. Thanks!